# How do I align a marqueed image to a certain position on the screen?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

My code currently looks a bit like this:

```
<marquee>
<img src="https://cdn140.picsart.com/274296681002211.png" alt="Mushroom" width="100" height="100">
</marquee>
```

I am a rookie and have tried using the **style=""** code but it seems to just break everything.

Comment: marquee tag is obsolete and should not be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @Pete Do you know any other ways to project images on the screen without using the marquee tag? If so, is there a way to loop it? Im guessing i will have to use <script> tag and do some JavaScript

Comment: do a search for css marquee

Comment: @Slyvick, what does "project images on the screen" mean?

Comment: @jnovack I have an image that currently moves on the screen every once and a while and when you hover over it it shakes. All I mean by project is basically show the image on the screen.

Comment: The `img` tag is what puts the image on the screen. You do not need any other tags to just have the image on the screen.

Comment: @jnovack I knew that part, problem was I didn't know how to make it move across the screen at random times and intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Put a div around your image than you can adjust the position easily with css. Check this link for further instructions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
  <marquee>
    <img src="https://cdn140.picsart.com/274296681002211.png" alt="Mushroom" width="100" height="100">
  </marquee>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image{
  position: absolute;
}
```

As an alternative you can use inline style with the style="" propertie.

```
<div style="position:absolute">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently and I tried everything. The only thing that worked for me was positioning the marquee tag itself.

This is my code; edit it to your liking:

```
<marquee direction="right" behaviour="scroll" width="520px" height="54"  style="position:relative; top:-45px; left:30px; ">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CBqPfyB/39a6b82755074cac22750d3a5b85837e-removebg-preview.png" alt="strawberry shortcake" width="100" height="100"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; ">
</marquee>
```

Hope this works!

(I am aware this question was 3 years ago lol, but I wanted to answer for whoever is looking for a solution)